# Ice transition particle effect

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, particles

We are small indie team developing a casual mobile game.

We are trying to implement an effect like the [normal-to-ice block transition in Angry Birds 2](https://youtu.be/q71RaKHn-iw?t=1227):

[image: Ice particle effect]

How can we implement an effect like this in Unity?

Comment: This looks like a straightforward use of a particle system, which Unity has built-in. What have you tried so far to duplicate this effect, based on your research in the Unity docs and particle system tutorials you've found online? How are your results so far differing from what you want?

Comment: i think it better to use some sprite-sheet for a 2d game for that type of 2d game. lots of particle systems like that makes your game slow

Comment: @virtouso Actually in some cases using particle systems instead of sprite animations can make your game faster. A particle generated by a particle system is far more lightweight than a game object with a sprite renderer.

Comment: @ DMGregory I am not the programmer on the team. Our programmer is a bit busy with his classes and coding contests. I was thinking about seeking some suggestions at the game dev forums, so that I can provide him with some references. I can let you know our results, when he starts working on it. He is familiar with Unity's particle systems.